# Abstract interface

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I'm defining an interface to handle different kind of input sources like CSV files, SQL Tables and so on, so that I can easily copy data from one to the other.
In order to achive this I have an interface for a reader and one for a writer. Since they have some common attributes I wanted to define an abstract interface of `ICommonContainer`.

The common container interface is incomplete, because it only defines a subset, so I figured that, if I add abstract, it shouldn't be instantiatable when applied to a class, but it is.

So is there some way to declare an interface as incomplete similar to an abstract class?

So the interfaces looks like this:

```
public interface ICommonContainer
{
    public void foo();
};

public interface Reader extends ICommonContainer
{
    public data read();
};

public interface Writer extends ICommonContainer
{
    public void write(data objects);
};
```

where reader and writer should be complete, but base is not.

Comment: You changed the name of the Base interface. Either make it `ICommonContainer` or `Base`.

Comment: *sigh*, it's just the concept, but I changed the names regardless...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `Abstract interface`. We make a class abstract in order to make it non-instantiable. And any interface by nature is non-instantiable only.

As far as your issue is concerned, you can make your class implement any number of interfaces. In your case, since your interfaces are a part of same inheritance hierarchy, you don't need to implement both `Base` interface, and `Reader` or `Writer` interface. So, let it implement either `Reader` or `Writer` interface.

---

On the other hand, if you want to make a class which only implements `ICommonContainer` interface, non-instatible, just make that class `abstract`. That will be enough.

```
public abstract class SomeClass implements ICommonContainer {
    // Either define the method in interface or leave it.
}
```

As in the above example, your `SomeClass` cannot be instantiated, as it is defined abstract.

Comment: I guess that's how I would have to do it. From the design perspective, I could of course do this, but that doesn't prevent others to make such a class not abstract and instantiating it. It feels a bit incomplete that I can not specify an interfaces as incomplete IMO.

Comment: @Devolus. Well, there is no way to prevent the implementing class from being instantiable. It's not in your control.

Answer (score 1):

> The common container interface is incomplete, because it only defines
>   a subset, so I figured that, if I add abstract, it shouldn't be
>   instantiatable when applied to a class, but it is.

No, you can't instantiate the interface.

And no, there is no way of preventing some class to implement that interface.

It is your job to implement `Reader` and `Writer` (*Your example names with applied Java naming conventions*) and you don't have to implement `Base`.

Comment: I was refereing to the class implementing the interface. I know that I can not instantiate the interface itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the interface package private which might accomplish what you want, but the bigger question is why?

In the Java library there are many interfaces that are "incomplete"; or a better way to explain it is they are partially complete.  List being one of them.

A List can be considered partially complete, because typically you need something more.  Such as ordering (ArrayList), or assurance of fast inserts (LinkedList).  The concrete classes take care of the completeness.

What you are trying to do goes against decent design principles.  I consider this poor design principles because you should you design your Interfaces as being enough for some level.  Given the list example, for some classes, knowing that there is an iteratable collection of objects is enough.  Which makes for a good interface design. The user of the interface is loosely coupled from the implementation of such.

Comment: Why is `List` and incomplete interface?

Comment: Why does it go against design principles?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't declare an interface abstract.

And you cannot prevent the world to have a class which implements your inteface and isn't abstract (if it is public).

I think this is ok, if someone can write a complete class using just your ICommonContainer, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "partial" interface the has to do with reading and another for writing, and another interface for the "missing" functionality.  Each user of your concrete class will then cast it to the interface it needs.